# how to make reactive combobox in r using gWidgets2RGtk2

Tags: r, combobox, gwidgets

For my GUI, i want to have 2 combo box.

combobox 1 to display Departments

combobox 2 to display items in the selected department from combobox1

So if the user selects "Electronics" as department in first combobox, **productElectronics** should be selected for 2nd comboBox else **productArts** should be selected.

```
library(gWidgets2RGtk2)
deptnames <- c("Arts","Electronics")
productArts <- c("Beads","Crayons")
productElectronics <- c("iPad","Apple Watch")

a1 <-c()
w <- gwindow("combobox example")
gp <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE,container=w)
dept <- gcombobox(deptnames, container = gp )

items <- gcombobox(a1, container = gp ,
               handler = function(h,...){
                # oldval <- svalue(dept)
                 if (svalue(dept) == "Arts")
                 {
                   a1 <- productArts
                 }
                 if(svalue(dept) == "Electronics")
                 {
                   a1 <- productElectronics                      
                 }
               }
)
```

For the above code nothing populates for any value selected in department combobox

Answer (score 0):

You should put a handler on the `deptnames` combobox to update the `items` combobox. You can mutate the items to select from with `items[] <- ...` and specify the selected one with `svalue(items, index=true) <- ...`. These would be based on the currently selected value of `deptnames` which is available through `svalue(deptnames)`. Hope that helps...