# How to wait for user to input values in combo box in gWidgets2RGtk2?

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

I want an user input and then source a file based on that input . The R code executes without letting user to select anything and just executes the next statement.

```
library(gWidgets2RGtk2)

w <- gwindow(title="Hello World",visible=TRUE)
g = ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, cont=w)
glabel("Please select your favorite subject", cont=g)
modeltype <- c("","Science","Math")
op1 <- gcombobox(modeltype, cont=g)

if (svalue(op1)=="Math"){
    source("Rscript1")
}else if (svalue(op1)=="Science"){
    source("Rscript2")
}else{
    source("Rscript3")
}
```

Now before I close the window or even select the option from my drop down list, it automatically takes **""** as the value and goes to the else statement and runs the **RScript3** . How can I pause the execution till I get the input from the user. 
Thanks.

Comment: Put your code in the handler like in [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204086/how-to-make-reactive-combobox-in-r-using-gwidgets2rgtk2/30312527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler function is called when an item is selected in the combo box. It is the place to put your actions:

```
addHandlerChanged(op1, handler=function(...){
    if (svalue(op1)=="Math"){
      source("Rscript1")
    }else if (svalue(op1)=="Science"){
      source("Rscript2")
    }else{
      source("Rscript3")
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would I execute the same thing with op1 and op2 i.e. run a script based on two conditions. Will I put the same handler in both the combo boxes? Even a theroritical reply is appreciated, I can adjust the code. Thanks.

Comment: You can create a function that will perform the actions, and set it as both comboboxes handlers. It will be called when any of the comboboxes changes